# VBA Make a Listbox Loop

Tags: vba, listbox, counter

I want to make a Listbox Loop but i get always a syntax error dont know why.

This is the actual Code:

```
'deselektion Listbox1
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
Next i

'deselektion Listbox2
    Dim f As Long
    For f = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    ListBox2.Selected(f) = False
    Next f
.
.
.
.
```

and so on until listbox 10

I thought it would be nice to rewrite the code.

```
For g= 1 To 10

 Dim i As Long
 For i = 0 To "ListBox & (g).ListCount - 1"
 ListBox & (g).Selected(i) = False
 Next i

Next g
```

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: What, exactly, is the syntax error?

Comment: The & is giving you trouble because it is telling VBA that there are two seperate items to be joined together as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign each listbox control to an index in a array of varients.

```
Dim listboxes(1 to 10) as Variant

Set listboxes(1) = Listbox1
...
Set listboxes(10) = Listbox10
```

Now you can Loop through the array you created with your code which I will borrow from above with some modifications

```
For g= 1 To 10
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To listboxes(g).ListCount - 1
       listboxes(g).Selected(i) = False
    Next i
Next g
```